# Android: Run Activity from Background

Tags: android

I have some Activities, activity A in which I start new activity B in new Task, so A goes to backgroung with it Task..in B I start C and from C i need to start A...i need to come back to first Task. How to do that ? Thanks !

Comment: Why won't you use service?) Or asyncTask? I don't get why do you want to have the activity in background?

Comment: I use service..Service Start activity only in new task..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use intents with Intent Flags.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

This should be used to start new activity , For example B and C in your case.

and

```
Intent intent= new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT));
```

can be used to relaunch A in your case. Hope this helps.